# What is the unique information on google plus login

Tags: authentication, google-plus

I managed to login with google plus, but after authenticating, I'm not sure which of the values is the unique value to authenticate the user.

After authenticating, I see a response with fields like:

access_token, code, id_token, but I'm not sure which to use?

Answer (score 0):

access_token: you use this to make API calls as the user who has just signed in - e.g. to retrieve profile information. This is valid for 1 hour.

id_token: this is a special signed blob which contains the user id of the signed in user, and the client ID of you application, can be used to identify the user. This is valid for one hour also.

code: you can send this to a server to exchange for an access token (to allow the server to make calls). This is valid for a few minutes.

In general you will use the access token to retrieve the user's name and photo as a next step:  https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information

Comment: Hmm, I got it, but my doubt is, what information should I store in database? Because Im creating a user, when the user makes the social login, so the next time he does it again, I want to check if an user already exists for him in database, otherwise I'll create it.

Comment: What I would do is store the user ID. For checking it, either send the code to the server, exchange it for an access token and hit the profile API, or use a client library and have it extract the user ID from the ID token for you. There's a bit more in that option here - http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/11/client-server-authentication-with-id.html